# Are all integrable functions continuous?

Tags: calculus

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function.

Suppose $f$ is integrable; is it continuous?

- My answer is that it is not continuous because we can have in $f(x)$ that can be broken into two intervals. Not sure if my answer is saying enough and my example is the function $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
       1, & x \neq 1 \\ 
       0, & x = 1
     \end{cases}.$$

Comment: I think you are correct, but I'd wait for more opinions, I'm not really the analyst type.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but there's something peculiar (unintentionally?) about the formatting of your function. Do you mean the function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is $1$ on $[0, 1]$ and $0$ elsewhere? (If so, this is a fine counterexample.)

Comment: I think I understand the example now, and I reformatted it to avoid the confusion I ran into; please edit it if it does not preserver your intention.

Comment: well integrable functions are usually required to be "at least" piecewise continuous so a function may not be continuous, but it is still integrable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your function on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Taking your example, you could define the function
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x = 0, \\ 0 & x \neq 0. \end{cases} $$
The intended domain of this definition is all of $\mathbb{R}$, and the function satisfies
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)| \, dx = 0. $$
However, $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer looks great. just to be sure the the upper sum of the partition $\{0,1-\delta,1\}$ is $\delta$ while the lower sum is $0$. Hence given any $\epsilon>0$ taking the partition $P=\{0,1-\delta,1\}$ with $\delta<\epsilon$ we get that $U(P)-L(P)=\delta<\epsilon$. So in fact this function is integrable. I suppose we can omit the proof it is not continuous.